# LINQ: Get values with latest date

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple test table:

```
Code FromDate   Name
---- ---------- -------
001  2012-11-30 bertie
001  2012-12-01 bert
002  2012-12-01 ernie
001  2012-12-02 bert
002  2012-12-02 ernie
001  2012-12-03 ernie
002  2012-12-04 bert
```

If I search in this table then I want the code with the latest 'from date'.
For example searching for 'ernie' should give this as result: '001 / 2012-12-03 / ernie'

Searching for 'bert' should give this as result: '002 / 2012-12-04 / bert'

If I search for 'er' I should get the 2 latest records: '001 / 2012-12-03 / ernie' and '002 / 2012-12-04 / bert'

This query isn't working:

```
from d in Data
where d.Name.ToUpper().Contains("ERNIE") && d.Code != null     
group d by d.Code into g
select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.FromDate).FirstOrDefault()
```

What is the best way of doing this?

The result should also give me the name without an sql query for each record.

**Update:**
Made the question more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
var query = (from d in Data
             group d by d.Code into g
             select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.FromDate).FirstOrDefault());

query = query.Where(d => d.Name.ToUpper().Contains("BERT") && d.Code != null);

query.Dump();
```